# Set priority for UIStackView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.2

how can i prioritize a label to be displayed fully and another label to display it too but if its too big it should make `...` in the UIStackview

[image]

This is my StackView

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example that follows what you want:

[image]

First, a UIStackView will actually make things harder here because we want to fine-tune the distance between each label. I just used leading and trailing constraints to layout each label in a line.

The trick is to set the proper *content compression resistance priority* and *content hugging priority* for each label. First, we want **0s** to always match the size of its content, so we set its content compression resistance priority to 1000. Content hugging priority can stay at the default of 250.

I also split the **@** sign into its own label, since we always want it to appear. Set its content compression resistance priority to 1000 and keep the content hugging priority at 250.

Next, for the **shrink_label**, we set the content compression resistance priority to 749 and the content hugging priority to 1000. That is, we want the **shrink_label** to never try and grow bigger than its text content size, and we want it to allow its content to be compressed if we need.

Finally, for the **laaabel** we set the content hugging priority to 1000 and the content compression resistance priority to 750. That is, the label will take up as much space as it can, and since its compression resistance priority is 1 higher than the **shrink_label**'s, the **shrink_label** will compress before the **laaabel**.

You can read about content compression and content hugging in the Apple docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html

The full source code for my example app is available here:

https://github.com/elliotfiske/StackOverflowContentHuggingExample

Comment: ___we want to fine-tune the distance between each label.___ - that's what the `UIStackView` for.

Comment: You forgot about constraint setting space between labels. Since all the labels have hugging priority of 1000, seems like this should be greaterThanOrEqual constraint.

Comment: Thank you. As I've noticed, changing the content hugging priority doesn't matter. It works even without changing it. I don't understand  what those both are and what are the differences between them (content hugging and compression resistance)